# Not able to render data from state into the React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to call Firebase and fetch the data in the form of JSON and then pass the objects of the JSON array to some other react-native component.

I am able to successfully make a call to Firebase and then fetch the array of JSON objects. Then later I am storing that list of JSON objects inside the STATE variable and then later trying to pass the object one by one to another react-native component.

Code:

```
class DisplayCardInformation extends Component 
{
const itemsRef = db.ref('firebaseLink/');

state = {
        listDataFromDB: null,
        lastKey: null
    };
componentDidMount() 
    {
        itemsRef.on('value', ( snapshot ) => {
            var data = snapshot.val();

            this.setState({
                listDataFromDB : snapshot.val(),
            });

            var keys = Object.keys(data);
            keys.forEach((key) => 
            { 
                this.setState({
                    lastKey: key
                });
            });
        });
    }

render() {

        this.state.listDataFromDB.map((listDataItem) => {
            return(
                <CardInformation listItem = {listDataItem} />
            );
        });     
    } 

}

export default DisplayCardInformation;
```

I am trying to pass the information to the CardInformation.

Error:

```
TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.listDataFromDB.map')

This error is located at:
    in DisplayCardInformation (at Home.js:33)
```

Comment: Set initial state to `state = {        listDataFromDB: [],` ... }

Comment: Because `this.state.listDataFromDB` is null on first render (before changing state). Add fallback: `this.state.listDataFromDB && this.state.listDataFromDB.map(...)`

Comment: Is it possible to see the data tree in Fairbase
Are you addressing the right child

Comment: yup I am able to print the data being fetched from the firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the initial value of the state to any array like:

```
state = {
        listDataFromDB: []
    };
```

What is happing in your case is that, when your component renders for the first time, it passes `null` to the child component.

Comment: After doing that I am getting an error like: "Nothing was returned from render". Is there some problem with the render function as well? Probably return is not getting executed.

Comment: Is it possible to see the data tree in Fairbase
Are you addressing the right child

Comment: @mshikher need more info regarding how your data is being retrieved.